# A technical question about the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How to prove that the boundary of the CLOSURE of $U$ has Lebesgue measure 0 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the statement in your question is not always true. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25993/sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-boundary for excellent answers. For related details, see also [Regular open set whose boundary has nonzero volume.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388677/regular-open-set-whose-boundary-has-nonzero-volume) and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24264/a-question-about-the-osgood-curve.

Comment: In fact, it's not hard to find examples where the measure of $U$ is arbitrarily small while the closure is the entire ${\bf R}^2$, just consider small balls around a countable dense subset.

Comment: @tomasz I agree; however, the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the empty set and thus has measure zero. So, I don't think it's a counterexample to the OP's claim.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Your links are helpful. I am preparing for my qualifying exam, and this problem is in the collection of past exams, so I didn't expect it to be wrong. Thank you very much for your help.