# Boundary of a Lebesgue measurable set E with $\lambda^n(E)≠0$ has Lebesgue Measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I could not think of any counter examples, so I am wondering whether this statement would be true, and ideas on how one could possible prove/disprove the statement?

Comment: The answer here may also be of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421934/set-e-subset-mathbbrn-of-positive-lebesgue-measure-such-that-the-lebesgue

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388677/regular-open-set-whose-boundary-has-nonzero-volume) and its answers. The gist is that such examples exist in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the interiors of space-filling Jordan curves.

Answer (score 0):

Well okay that was A stupid question I just realized. It is enough to look at $\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q$ as a counterexample in $\mathbb R$, which obviously has infinite Lebesgue measure but is composed solely of boundary points.